# How to Refresh data using Riverpod in a function outside the WidgetRef ref

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I am using Flutter Riverpod to get data from Api in a user/profile screen.

This is my code to construct the UI

```
Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final profileData = ref.watch(profileDataProvider);
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: topBar,
        drawer: const Menu(),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: SizedBox(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                profileData.when(
                  data: (data) {
                    String image = data.data.userProfile.picture.thumbnail;
                    if (profileData.isRefreshing) {
                      return const CircularProgressIndicator.adaptive();
                    }
                    return Column(
                      children: [
                        const SizedBox(height: 20),
                        Stack(
                          clipBehavior: Clip.none,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Container(
                              width: 200.0,
                              height: 200.0,
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                image: DecorationImage(
                                  image: CachedNetworkImageProvider(image),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Positioned(
                              bottom: 5,
                              right: 5,
                              child: IconButton(
                                onPressed: () {
                                  showModalBottomOptions(context);
                                },
                                icon: Icon(
                                  Icons.add_a_photo_outlined,
                                  color: ColorConstants.iconTextFieldColor,
                                  size: 40,
                                ),
                              ),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(height: 20),
                        const Divider(color: Colors.grey),
                        Text(
                          '${data.data.userProfile.firstName} ${data.data.userProfile.lastName}',
                        ),
                        Text(data.data.userProfile.email),
                        Text(data.data.userProfile.mobile),
                      ],
                    );
                  },
                  error: ((error, stackTrace) {
                    return Text(error.toString());
                  }),
                  loading: CircularProgressIndicator.adaptive,
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 20),
                const Divider(color: Colors.grey),
                const Text('OS Type (Andriod, iOS, Chrome)'),
                const SizedBox(height: 20),
                const Text('OS Version'),
                const SizedBox(height: 20),
                const Text('DeviceId'),
                const SizedBox(height: 20),
                const Divider(color: Colors.grey),
                OutlinedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => const ChangePassword(),
                        ));
                  },
                  child: Text(
                    'Change Password',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: ColorConstants.buttonTextColor,
                      fontSize: TextSize.textButtonSize,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

The function showModalBottomOptions shows two options, (Camera and Gallery) to select the image, after that I have a function that takes the image and upload it to the server.

The App works, but the problem I'm facing is that after the picture is uploaded, I do not know how to show the new image in the UI, because the showModalBottomOptions function is out of the build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) I cannot access it.

How can I call the Api again to refresh the image and show it to the user?

I did not include the showModalBottomOptions to make this shorter, If needed, I can post it.

Thank you for your time, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume `showModalBottomOptions` calls [`showModalBottomSheet`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showModalBottomSheet.html), in which you should return the value of it which is a `Future`.

```dart
Future<void> showModalBottomOptions(BuildContext context) {
  return showModalBottomSheet(...);
}
```

In your `onPressed` callback, make it an asnyc function and await the call to `showModalBottomOptions`. In the next line, make the necessary operation with `ref`:

```dart
onPressed: () async {
  await showModalBottomOptions(context);

  // You can use `ref` here
  ref.invalidate(profileDataProvider);
}
```

---

You don't necessarily make the method returns `Future<void>`, you can also use `Future<bool>` for example, if you want to conditionally refresh the data based on the successness of the image upload:

```dart
Future<bool> showModalBottomOptions(BuildContext context) {
  // Do some logic here
}
```

```dart
onPressed: () async {
  final isSuccess = await showModalBottomOptions(context);
  if (isSuccess) {
    ref.invalidate(profileDataProvider);
  }
}
```